# The view doesn't get result from Firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

```
struct StaffAccount: Identifiable {
    var id: String
    var email: String
    var password: String
    var status: String
}

class StaffAccountModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var staffAccount0 = [StaffAccount]()
    func getData() {
        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        db.collection("users").getDocuments { snapshot, error in
            if error == nil {
                if let snapshot = snapshot {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.staffAccount0 = snapshot.documents.map { d in
                            return StaffAccount(id: d.documentID,
                                                     email: d["email"] as? String ?? "",
                                                     password: d["password"] as? String ?? "",
                                                status: d["status"] as? String ?? "")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else {
                //Handle the error
            }
            
        }
    }
}

struct TrainingView: View {
    @ObservedObject var staffAccount = StaffAccountModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List(staffAccount.staffAccount0) { item in
                    Text("\(item.status)")   
        }
}
}
```

I made that after registering a new user, his data is added to the firebase and moved to the firestore with names corresponding to those that I wrote. I need to get the word corresponding to the key "status" from the "staff" collection, but for some reason I can't get the data. I see an empty result in View
I did similar actions with another collection and got the result in View.
Everything that is written in code corresponds to what the firestore shows

Comment: 1) You never call `getData` 2) You never instantiate `StaffAccountModel` -- you just have `ViewModel` 3) You should use `@StateObject` in the View in which the ObservableObject is owned.

Comment: Yeah, sorry about the 2nd. I forgot to change it. Now I’ve changed it. So I’ve changed to StateObject but nothing has changed. And yeah, I think it’s good idea to use getData, but how will be better using it here? :)

Comment: If you never call `getData`, the you'll never get the data from Firebase.